# Can I get the latest updated row to the top

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table that stores some data like below

[image: TableR]

Every time a user adds a new resistor it should count the number of times they add that resistor.

So I did it by this

```sql
SELECT RT_resistor, COUNT(RT_resistor) as qty
FROM RMR_RT_resistor
WHERE location = 'KOG' AND PL = 'PBW' AND Submit_User='1' AND RT_label='Mohm' AND resistor_type='MF'
GROUP BY RT_resistor
```

[image]

This is the result of that query

The point is I need to get the last entered resistor row to the top.

*Lets think if I entered 20 for RT_resistor values. So then the row which is contains 20 should be in the top of the table with the qty 3*

Comment: Please don't use images for data. Use formatted text.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to order using the max value of the `Date`:

```sql
SELECT RT_resistor, COUNT(RT_resistor) AS qty
FROM RMR_RT_resistor
WHERE location = 'KOG' AND PL = 'PBW' AND Submit_User = '1' AND RT_label = 'Mohm' AND
      resistor_type = 'MF'
GROUP BY RT_resistor
ORDER BY MAX(Date) DESC;
```

Note that each resistor group has multiple dates.  The above logic is to choose the most recent date as a proxy for each entire resistor group.